# Three.js OrbitControls Rotating Around a ring

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have an OrbitControls camera which rotates around the dot: target = player.position.x, y and z. It's pretty ok, but the player is right in the centre of the screen. I need a camera to rotate around a ring...
[first picture: target is in the centre, second: target is always placed to the left of the centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUVXI.png)

Let me explain:
Here is my code:

```
controls.target.x = player.position.x;
controls.target.y = player.position.y+3;
controls.target.z = player.position.z;
```

So we rotate around a fixed dot.

But I need a dot which changes its position depending on controls.getAzimuthalAngle() or something else.
The camera must be like in GTA V or other games, where a player is not right in the centre of the screen, but a little to the left, so it's more convenient for, for example, aiming, the player does not interfere with the aim in the centre.

Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for a 3rd person camera you constantly target the camera at the player (or some offset from the player, or some object attached to the player)

You then have the camera follow the player over time.

In the code below there is a `cameraRig` that follows the player. The camera rig is there so we don't have to do any math to keep the camera above the ground. Similarly there is a `camTarget` which is attached to the player. This is so the camera looks at about shoulder height.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const keys = {};
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 500;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  
  // put the camera 5 units above the rig
  const cameraRig = new THREE.Object3D();
  cameraRig.add(camera);
  camera.position.y = 5;
  scene.add(cameraRig);
  cameraRig.position.z = 5;

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  
  {
    const size = 200;
    const divisions = 100;
    const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
    scene.add(gridHelper);
  }

  const boxWidth = 0.5;
  const boxHeight = 2;
  const boxDepth = 0.5;
  const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(boxWidth, boxDepth, boxHeight);

  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'red'});
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  const player = new THREE.Object3D();
  const camTarget = new THREE.Object3D();

  cube.position.y = boxHeight / 2;  // move cube above ground
  player.add(cube);
  camTarget.position.y = boxHeight * 3 / 2;  // target 2/3ds up the player
  player.add(camTarget);
  scene.add(player);
  
  

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }
  
  const moveDir = new THREE.Vector3();
  const camTargetPos = new THREE.Vector3();
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;
    deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    // left, right, a, d
    const dx = ((keys[37] || keys[65]) ?  1 : 0) + 
               ((keys[39] || keys[68]) ? -1 : 0);
    // up, down, w, s
    const dy = ((keys[38] || keys[87]) ?  1 : 0) + 
               ((keys[40] || keys[83]) ? -1 : 0);
    const playerMoveSpeed = 10; // units per second
    camera.getWorldDirection(moveDir);
    moveDir.y = 0; // no up down movement
    moveDir.normalize();
    // move player forward/back
    player.position.addScaledVector(moveDir, dy * playerMoveSpeed * deltaTime);
    // rotate direction 90 degrees
    const t = moveDir.x;
    moveDir.x = moveDir.z;
    moveDir.z = -t;
    // move player left/right
    player.position.addScaledVector(moveDir, dx * playerMoveSpeed * deltaTime);
    
    // if the cameraRig is too far from
    // player then move it
    const maxDistance = 6;
    const maxCamMoveSpeed = 0.015;
    const distance = cameraRig.position.distanceTo(player.position);
    if (distance > maxDistance) {
      const amount = maxCamMoveSpeed;
      cameraRig.position.lerp(player.position, amount);
    }

    camTarget.getWorldPosition(camTargetPos);
    camera.lookAt(camTargetPos);
     

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  });
}



main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" tabindex="0"></canvas>
```

3rd person cameras can be hard. The one above is too simple. You can think of it as if the cameraRig is being dragged on a string behind the player. If you back up the camera doesn't move. It only moves if the the camera is maxDistance away.

It's common to instead put the camera on a stick so if you walk backward the stick pushed the camera back.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const keys = {};
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 500;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  
  // put the camera 5 units above the rig
  const cameraRig = new THREE.Object3D();
  cameraRig.add(camera);
  camera.position.y = 5;
  scene.add(cameraRig);
  cameraRig.position.z = 5;

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  
  {
    const size = 200;
    const divisions = 100;
    const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
    scene.add(gridHelper);
  }

  const boxWidth = 0.5;
  const boxHeight = 2;
  const boxDepth = 0.5;
  const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(boxWidth, boxDepth, boxHeight);

  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'red'});
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  const player = new THREE.Object3D();
  const camTarget = new THREE.Object3D();

  cube.position.y = boxHeight / 2;  // move cube above ground
  player.add(cube);
  camTarget.position.y = boxHeight * 3 / 2;  // target 2/3ds up the player
  player.add(camTarget);
  scene.add(player);
  
  

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }
  
  const moveDir = new THREE.Vector3();
  const camTargetPos = new THREE.Vector3();
  const rigTargetPos = new THREE.Vector3();
  
  function moveCameraToDistance(desiredDistance) {
    const maxCamMoveSpeed = 0.02;
    
    // delta from player to rig
    rigTargetPos.subVectors(cameraRig.position, player.position);
    // remove up/down
    rigTargetPos.y = 0; // no up/down
    // make unit vector
    rigTargetPos.normalize();
    // make desiredDistance long
    rigTargetPos.multiplyScalar(desiredDistance);
    // add player position
    rigTargetPos.add(player.position);
    // move rig toward that position
    const curDistance = cameraRig.position.distanceTo(player.position);
    cameraRig.position.lerp(
        rigTargetPos,
        THREE.MathUtils.lerp(
            maxCamMoveSpeed,
            1, 
            THREE.MathUtils.clamp(1 - curDistance / desiredDistance, 0, 1)));
  }
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;
    deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    // left, right, a, d
    const dx = ((keys[37] || keys[65]) ?  1 : 0) + 
               ((keys[39] || keys[68]) ? -1 : 0);
    // up, down, w, s
    const dy = ((keys[38] || keys[87]) ?  1 : 0) + 
               ((keys[40] || keys[83]) ? -1 : 0);
    const playerMoveSpeed = 10; // units per second
    camera.getWorldDirection(moveDir);
    moveDir.y = 0; // no up down movement
    moveDir.normalize();
    // move player forward/back
    player.position.addScaledVector(moveDir, dy * playerMoveSpeed * deltaTime);
    // rotate direction 90 degrees
    const t = moveDir.x;
    moveDir.x = moveDir.z;
    moveDir.z = -t;
    // move player left/right
    player.position.addScaledVector(moveDir, dx * playerMoveSpeed * deltaTime);
    
    // keep camera at distance
    const minDistance = 4;
    const maxDistance = 6;
    const distance = cameraRig.position.distanceTo(player.position);
    if (distance > maxDistance) {
      moveCameraToDistance(maxDistance);
    } else if (distance < minDistance) {
      moveCameraToDistance(minDistance);
    }

   // compute point from player in direction of rig 
    // at desired distance

    camTarget.getWorldPosition(camTargetPos);
    camera.lookAt(camTargetPos);
     

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  });
}



main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" tabindex="0"></canvas>
```

You then need to deal with things like stuff getting between the camera and the player. (some games fade that stuff out).  You also need to deal with say walking through a door. For a while player will be on one side of the door and the camera on the other (or rather opposite sides of the doorway so does the camera come down so it can see through the door? Does the wall fade out? Does the camera jump through the door and start looking from some other positions. Rumor is in Mario 64 one programmer worked on the camera an entire year and nothing else.)

Note that some of the code above only works in the special case that `someObject.position` is a world space postion (the object has no parent objects, or if it does all the parents have position = 0,0,0 rotation = 0,0,0, scale = 1,1,1). If the object does have parents then you'd need to get the world position with

```
const wp = new THREE.Vector3();
someObject.getWorldPosition(wp);
```

And if you wanted to apply a world position you'd need to do more work to make the position relative of the parent. For now, to keep it simple, I just used objects who's world position is their position.